# ActiveRecord MySQL Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm having an issue connecting to an external AWS Aurora MySQL in my Rails app in production.

Here is the setup:

- One main PostgreSQL database for the app
- One external (AWS Aurora MySQL) database used as a reader for huge datasets

In development, everything works fine, but when I deploy to Heroku, I can only successfully query one table of the external database. When I create another table I get this error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Lost connection
to MySQL server during query: SELECT `TMC_Identification`.`direction`,
`TMC_Identification`.`miles`, `TMC_Identification`.`road`, 
`TMC_Identification`.`tmc` FROM `TMC_Identification`) :
1: <%= raw(@tmcs.to_json) %>
```

- Rails 5.2
- Ruby 2.5.3

**Models:**

```
class TmcReading < ApplicationRecord

  establish_connection(:tmc_data)
  self.table_name = "TMC_Readings"

end

class TmcIdentification < ApplicationRecord

  establish_connection(:tmc_data)
  self.table_name = "TMC_Identification"

end
```

**database.yml:**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

production:
  <<: *default
  database: production
  username: admin
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

tmc_data:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: tmc_data
  username: <%= Rails.application.credentials.tmc_data_db[:username] %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.credentials.tmc_data_db[:password] %>
  host: tmc-data.cluster-ro-xyz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  port: 3306
```

**Controller Action**

```
  def tmc_identifications

    @tmcs = TmcIdentification.all.select(:direction, :miles, :road, :tmc)

  end
```

**View**

```
<%= raw(@tmcs.to_json) %>
```

Everything works fine in development, but not in production. The same database and credentials are used in production for the "tmc_data" connection.

I assume I'm having some thread safety issues, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem is the following way:

**Models:**

```
class TmcData < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection(:tmc_data)
end

class TmcReading < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "TMC_Readings"
end

class TmcIdentification < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "TMC_Identification"
end
```

More details: https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/managing-multiple-databases-in-a-single-rails-application/

Also, I stopped connecting to the same secondary database with my development and production environment.